# wp pagination dont show in homepage

Tags: wordpress, pagination

**Now i tried to go pdf-market.ir/?paged=2 but it's show 404 Error !**
check site, [site](http://pdf-market.ir) [search](http://pdf-market.ir/?s=%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8)

i 1day tried to solve this problem but don't succed.
my codes for loop in index.php

```
<ul class="page_result">
              <?php
              //$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') :  1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'stock' => 1,
            'posts_per_page' => 16,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => 1,
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;   ?>
          <div class="bookbox">
              <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <div class="bookbox-img">
               <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" style="margin-left: -20px" width="200px" height="200px" />'; ?>
               </div>
              </a>
              <div class="bookbox-bookname"><a data-tooltip="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="bookname tooltip" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <?php $mid_var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'پدیداورنده',true);
            if(isset($mid_var) && !empty($mid_var)) : ?>
              <div class="bookbox-dtibook"><span class="garyYekan10">پدیدآورنده:</span> 
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'پدیداورنده',true); ?>
             </div><?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $mid_var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ناشر',true);
            if(isset($mid_var) && !empty($mid_var)) : ?>
              <div class="bookbox-dtibook"><span class="garyYekan10">ناشر: </span>
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ناشر',true); ?>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $mid_var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'نوبت چاپ',true);
            if(isset($mid_var) && !empty($mid_var)) : ?>
              <div class="bookbox-dtibook"><span class="garyYekan10">نوبت چاپ:</span>
                <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'نوبت چاپ',true); ?>
              </div> 
            <?php endif; ?>
              <div class="bookbox-price"><span class="garytahoma8">قیمت: </span> <?php woocommerce_template_loop_price() ?> </div> 
                    <?php $mid_var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'موجودی',true);
            if(isset($mid_var) && !empty($mid_var)) : ?>
              <div class="bookbox-price"><span class="garytahoma8">موجودی: </span><span class="fontgreen10">
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'موجودی',true); ?>
              </span> </div><?php endif; ?>
              <a alt="مشخصات کتاب" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div title="مشخصات کتاب" alt="مشخصات کتاب" class="bookbox-bookinfo"></div></a>
              <a alt="خرید کتاب" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>&add-to-cart=<?php the_id(); ?>">
              <div alt="خرید کتاب" class="bookbox-addcart"></div>
              </a>


              </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>   

<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
    wp_pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

and my code in function.php > pagination

```
<?php
function wp_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 12345678;
    $page_format = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type'  => 'array'
    ) );
    if( is_array($page_format) ) {
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
                echo '<div><ul>';
                foreach ( $page_format as $page ) {
                        echo "<li>$page</li>";
                }
               echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

this is all...
in searches and archives is show pagination but
in home page and example:site.com dont show pagination and it's place just free and no code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code this will work for you

```
<?php
                                global $query_string;
                                query_posts($query_string . "post_type=product&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=16");  
                                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                               <?php the_title(); ?>

                            <?php endwhile;
                                endif; ?>
                                <?php pagination_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Put this code in your functions.php file.

```
function pagination_numeric_posts_nav() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class=""><ul class="pagination">' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

css for pagination.

```
.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
    background-color: #6FB7E9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px;
    padding: 0.75rem;
}

.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a {
    background-color: #3C8DC5;
}
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem. Please provide complete description of the issue you are facing. it's working fine for me

Comment: check 2new line in post <3